# TabLayout or horizontal scrollview Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablayout

Image for the TabLayout that I wanted to achieve.
[image]

Can somebody shows me the way to achieve this?

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="center"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I already set the attributes `app:tabMode="scrollable"` and `app:tabGravity="center"` but all the tabs just stick to the left in the layout.

I wanna achieve the result like the above image no matter how many the tabs are. Means the position of the tabs will away at the center or the tablayout.

PageFragment.java:

```
package com.example.testing;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;


// In this case, the fragment displays simple text based on the page
public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    private int mPage;

    public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view;
        textView.setText("Fragment #" + mPage);
        return view;
    }


}
```

SampleFragmentPagerAdapter.java:

```
package com.example.testing;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;



public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };
    private Context context;

    public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }
}
```

TabActivity.java:

```
package com.example.testing;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TabAcitivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tab_layout);

        // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),TabAcitivity.this));

        // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

[image]

The tabs start from the left. How do I place it to make it start at the middle? Or is it better to use a horizontal scrollable ListView?

Comment: Can you post your java code?

Comment: @SachinSaxena Please check for the codes

Comment: please check after removing app:tabGravity="center" from the layout. I think it should work.

Comment: @SachinSaxena The tabs start from the left. How do I place it to make it start at the middle? Or is it better to use a horizontal scrollable ListView?

Answer (score 2):

use this for scrolling tabs:

```
sliding_tabs.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
```

For any other reference please have a look at the following url.
https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout

Comment: I want to make my tabs start at the center of the layout, if wanna do so, is it sets a margin or padding to the TabLayout?